# Unable to update/delete related model in the save() method of a model

Tags: python, django

I have two Django models:

```
from django.db import models

class Policy(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        quote = self.documents.get(document_type=DocumentType.quote)
        if self.status == 0:
            quote.delete()
        elif self.status == 1:
            new_quote_content = create_new_quote()
            quote.s3_file.save(quote.name, File(new_quote_content))

        super().save(*args, *kwargs)


class Document(models.Model):
    policy = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Policy,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="documents",
    )
    s3_file = models.FileField(
        storage=S3Storage(aws_s3_bucket_name="policy-documents"),
        upload_to=get_document_s3_key,
        max_length=255,
    )
```

I want to delete/update the document when the policy status is updated and I've overriden the save() method in Policy to do it. However, neither the doc deletion nor the doc's FieldFile update works in the save() method. If I move them to outside the save() method, everything works.

Does someone understand what's the issue here?

Comment: `if self.status = "X":` also this should be `if self.status == "X":`

Comment: and `self.status` seems to be `IntegerField`... how can it be compared with `str`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not calling the super method to save the model. To override a model it has to be something like this as given in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) of Django.

```
from django.db import models
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        do_something()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
        do_something_else()
```

Comment: It is. Sorry, I forgot to copy that line before.

Answer (score 0):

The save() was being called from a Policy ModelAdmin with a inlined Document form set. After it was run, Django executed the ModelAdmin's save_related() method, which saved the Document form set data, overwriting the Document changes I had just saved in save(). I solved it by overriding save_related() and deleting/updating the document after form.save_m2m() and form.save_formset().